# Unclear about node.js; one variable for everyone?

Tags: node.js, var

I am using this simple WebSockets implementation for node.js https://npmjs.org/package/ws

Wondering if vars on the server are user or server specific by default...? I can't get my head around many users and one server... node seems like Schrodinger's cat right now (it both is and it isn't)

If I set up the server:

```
var thing=(thing>0)?thing:0; 
console.log('thing='+thing+' this only seems to happen when the server born, hmm ok...');

//Normal require/set up ws stuff...
wss.on('connection',function(ws){
    thing=Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
    ws.on('message',function(_){
        ws.send('reply: thing='+thing);
        });
    });
```

And the client:

```
ws=new WebSocket('ws://'+somehost+':'+(someport));
ws.onopen=function(){
    ws.onmessage=function(_){console.log(_.data);}
    ws.send('question: what is the thing now?');
    }

$('#button').click(function(){ws.send('question: what is the thing now?');});
```

now If I have two users (A & B) that go on the site one after the other:

- user A will open the page and see the var as 1st random number
- user B will see it as 2nd random number
- A could click the button then see it as the second random number
- if B clicked the button B would also see the 2nd random number

...Because B changed it on the server for everyone?

Am I doing this right? To make a variable on the server that becomes specific to connection **with no (zero) helpful info from the client?**

If I am unclear what I would like to do is that A always sees the the number it sets and B always sees the number it sets.

Can/does server know the difference?

Is it just a matter of where to place the code? **(like the example shows the console log only at the servers birth)**

Or could it be similar to the difference between Javascript copying an object vs referring to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you place the `var` keyword. Where you have it now, the scope is outside the function that executes on a new connection, so you have one `thing` shared between every connection.

If you move the `var` keyword into your function like so:

```
var thing = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
```

Then `thing` will be local to that function's context which means there will be two separate `thing`s (one for each connection) since the function is executed once for every new connection.

Comment: WOW you just made it make sence to me in so little words! There is now TWO of the same thing! :D

Answer (score 0):

The global `thing` variable is re-randomized every time someone connects. There's only one instance of that variable.

If you want per-user variables, use an object dict.

```
var things = {}
```

And then on connection you can do

```
things[unique_user_id] = // whatever
```

I think somewhere in that connection object, `ws`, there should be a unique identifier that you can use.

Comment: but then how does the server know what part of the object is you next time you click? If the sever made the number why should the client need to tell the server what the number was?

Comment: @BENZ.404: Eh? As long as the connection is kept open, the ID won't change. The client doesn't need to know what it is. The ID is available for the entire `wss.on('connection',function(ws){` scope. You can use it inside of the `.on('message'` bits too.

Comment: I haven't used the `ws` library specifically so I'm not 100% sure if it provides this ID to you, but if not, you can generate a GUID inside the on-connection function (remembering to use the `var` keyword *inside*) and you'll be fine. Or even just store everything you need right in there (like Paulpro suggests) and you don't even need to worry about it. It just depends where you need to access the var from; sometimes having a global object is useful if you need to access user data from other scopes, or for knowing how many users are connected (remember to delete on disconnect).

Comment: I understand completely now